# Генерация списка всевозможных строк с добавлением точки

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть строка, например `'abcd'`. Мне нужно сгенерировать всевозможные вариации этой строки с добавлением точки, например:

```
'a.bcd'
'ab.cd'
'abc.d'
...
'a.b.cd'
'a.b.c.d'
'a.b.c.d.'
```

Comment: `abcd.` должно быть?

Comment: И также `.abcd`?

Comment: И важна ли именно такая последовательность, как в примере? Т.е. сначала все варианты с одной строчкой, потом с двумя, и т.д. Или всё равно как, главное все варианты перебрать?

Comment: И что делать если в исходной строке уже есть точки? Можно ли ставить свои точки рядом с точками из исходной строки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно скомбинировать список из строки `abcd` со списком из `['','.']`. Из строк abcd делаем список `['','a','b','c','d']`. С помощью `itertools.product()` делаем все возможные расположения под список символов из списка `['','.']`. Потом суммируем через `zip()`.

```
import itertools

text = 'abcd'
symbols = ['', *list(text)]
filler = ['','.']  # Список для создания комбинаций расположения пустого места и точки
combine = [list(zip(symbols, r)) for r in list(itertools.product(filler, repeat=len(symbols)))]
print(*[''.join([c for item in row for c in item]) for row in combine], sep='\n')
```

Вывод

```
abcd
abcd.
abc.d
abc.d.
ab.cd
ab.cd.
...
.a.b.c.d
.a.b.c.d.
```